# "-map_metadata -1" not working on my compiled ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editor, linux, metadata

The problem is:

When I use my compiled version of ffmpeg, it does NOT remove any metadata.

I've compiled/built ffmpeg using the (general) guide on https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu many times before and except for this issue with "-map_metadata -1" not working, everything else works great with my ffmpeg, encoding, decoding, video, audio, ...

So, is there a configure option or an --enable-*** switch, when building ffmpeg, that is missing in the https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu guide, so that my (compiled) ffmpeg will work with "-map_metadata -1" to remove metadata.?